# Как компилятору GCC дать путь где искать библиотеки?

Tags: c, dll

Есть исходный файл:
**main.c**
И есть папка с библиотеками:
**/libs/**
И библиотека:
**MyLib.dll**
Если динамическая библиотека находится рядом с исполняемым файлом то все нормально:
**gcc main.c -o main.exe MyLib.dll**
Я получаю исполняемый файл который нормально работает и нормально вызывает методы из библиотеки

Но если я хочу брать библиотеки с папки libs то у меня проблема и вот единственное к чему я смог дойти так ето:
**gcc main.c -o main.exe -Wl,"D:/MyProgram/libs/MyLib.dll"**
Програма компилируется без ошибок но при запуске я получаю:
"Не удается продолжить выполнение кода, поскольку система не обнаружила MyLib.dll"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Answer (score -1):

есть пара путей. Первый функция LoadLibraryEx (libloaderapi.h)
Загружает указанный модуль в адресное пространство вызывающего процесса. Указанный модуль может привести к загрузке других модулей.

Второй Функция SetDllDirectory (winbase.h)
Добавляет каталог в путь поиска, используемый для поиска библиотек DLL для приложения.